# Finding closest feature of polyline layer to point layer using ArcPy with ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcpy, point, spatial-join

In ArcGIS Pro, I have 2 layers.

One layer called X has data points which contains data for count points in a certain point of a road. This layer has an attribute (column) called Direction. This is supposed to show what direction the traffic is flowing (N for North, W for west, S for South and E for east) there are often two identical points in the same location, of course both are different in their ID and data it contains, and the main difference is the direction of travel.

I also have another layer called Y which has polyline data and shows the roadlinks for an entire county. This layer has also a similar attribute (column) which nominates the direction of travel. Similarly to layer X, Often in this layer Y, there are two identical polylines, each has a separate uniqie ID, where the only difference between them is direction. I want to update the layer X with a new column, where it copies the ID of the closest roadlink from layer Y, with the condition that the direction matches. This means, if i have a pair of points in layer X (lets call them ID: 001 direction N and ID 002 direction S), i want to assign to them te corresponding roadlink ID, which is closest but also matching the direction of travel (for example closest would result two polyline features, but One would be direction N and one direction S, so i want the correct roadlink id assigned to the correct data point of layer X.

I have tried this code to try and iterate through each point of layer X, find the closest match ID on layer Y, and save it to a dictionary, then using this dictionary to update the target layer and target field.

```py
closest_roadlinks = {}

with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(layerX, ["OBJECTID", "SHAPE@", "Direction_of_travel", "ClosestRoadlinkID"]) as cursorX:
    for rowX in cursorX:
        point = rowX[1]
        direction = rowX[2]
        arcpy.SelectLayerByLocation_management(layerY, "WITHIN_A_DISTANCE", point, distance)
        potential_roadlinks = []
        
        with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(layerY, ["OBJECTID", "SHAPE@", "CALCULATED_DIRECTION"]) as cursorY:
            for rowY in cursorY:
                if rowY[2] == direction:
                    distance = point.distanceTo(rowY[1])
                    potential_roadlinks.append((rowY[0], distance))
        
        closest_roadlinks[rowX[0]] = potential_roadlinks
        arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(layerY, "CLEAR_SELECTION")

with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(layerX, ["OBJECTID", "ClosestRoadlinkID"]) as cursorX:
    for rowX in cursorX:
        if rowX[0] in closest_roadlinks:
            
            potential_roadlinks = closest_roadlinks[rowX[0]]
            if potential_roadlinks:
                closest_roadlink = min(potential_roadlinks, key=lambda x: x[1])
                rowX[1] = closest_roadlink[0]  # Update with ObjectID
            cursorX.updateRow(rowX)

print("Closest roadlink IDs updated successfully.")
```

but the code is not working, as it only updates the first row of target layer. For some reason the dictionary closest_roadlink is populated only by one element.

Comment: In your selectbylocation tool what is `distance` set to, it's not shown in the code?

Comment: Hi! the distance is set to 500 meters

Comment: Before the updatecursor section, put in a print statement and print `closest_roadlinks` dictionary and verify it has what you expect in it.